# Trying To Grab First 50 Points of A Graph MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I want to plot just the first 50 points of the following function in MATLAB and I'm having difficulty finding out how to do this, I genuinely cannot find the command or much that is similar online. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you in advance for all the help, anything is appreciated.

```
>> p=pi;
>> x=[0:0.1:4*p];
>> y = exp(-0.4*x).*sin(x);
>> plot(x,y), plot(x(1:50)) %%%this is one of my attempts
>> title ('MATLAB PRACTICE');
>> xlabel('x-Axis'); 
>> ylabel('y-Axis'); 
>> grid on
```

Comment: `plot(x(1:50))` only contains the `x` values. What about the `y` values?

Comment: What would be the syntax for that? because I'm only interested in taking the first 50 data points along the x-axis right? but when I do this, I just get a linear function which I know is not correct.

Comment: Each `x` point has to have a `y` value, right? Or else you're not plotting anything.

Comment: right that makes sense absolutely, so then the format would be something like plot(x(1:50),y); right?

Comment: You only want as many `y` values as there are `x` points...

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but it is instructive to break the problem into steps.

Think of it this way: you want to first select the first 50 values of x and y, and then plot those.

You can do that like so:

```
xSubset = x(1:50);
ySubset = y(1:50);
plot(xSubset, ySubset);
```

The syntax x(1:50) can be used to select a portion of x (or any vector).

We can accomplish the same thing without creating the temporary vectors, which may be desirable because it is more concise (and less typing):

```
plot(x(1:50), y(1:50));
```